# How to make Android TestRunner wait until activity finishes

Tags: android, testing, wait, activity-finish, test-runner

I am closing an Activity at the end of a testcase, so that it is null at the beginning of the next testcase:

```
public void test1() throws Exception {

    //activity is calling the RegisterActivity in onCreate
    activity = getActivity();

    // register next activity that need to be monitored.
    RegisterActivity nextActivity = (RegisterActivity) getInstrumentation()
        .waitForMonitorWithTimeout(activityMonitor, 5);
    // next activity is opened and captured.
    assertNotNull(nextActivity);
    if (nextActivity != null) {
        nextActivity.finish();
    }
}

public void test2() throws Exception {
    //nextActivity.finish() from the previous test has not yet finished

    //body of test2
    //...
    //...
}
```

If I set a Thread sleep in test1 then problem is solved:

```
    if (nextActivity != null) {
        nextActivity.finish();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    }
```

Is there a better way to to this? Is there a method that blocks the TestRunner until nextActivity is finished?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `new thread` for the nextActivity to run in. After calling the `thread.start()` method, call `thread.join()` where you want the TestRunner blocked.